# VBA run Access Report with Parameter based on query

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vba

I want to automate some of our Access Reports with a VBA script. But when I want to run them with `DoCmd.OpenReport`, I have the problem that every Report has a Popup for some Parameters coming from the underlying Query.

This is how the Parameter looks like in the Query:

```
PARAMETERS [Time] Text ( 255 );
```

I googled a lot and tried with:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "B_My_Report", acViewPreview, , "[Time]= 423"
```

But this didn't work; the popup still comes and when I enter nothing, the query will fail because *Time* parameter is empty.

Is there a way I can call the Report with the Parameter value. I read a lot of Suggestion to remove the Parameter completely and use the `where` condition in `OpenReport`. But I can't change these Queries because they aren't made and maintained by me. I only have to run them sometimes. So I would love to have a solution without touching the Report or the Query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your Access version is >= 2010, consider the [DoCmd.SetParameter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194182(v=office.14).aspx).

This query is the *Record Source* for my report:

```sql
PARAMETERS which_id Long;
SELECT rmy.id, rmy.reportDate, rmy.gainOrLoss
FROM record_matYields AS rmy
WHERE rmy.id=[which_id] OR [which_id] Is Null;
```

So then I can assign a value for the parameter and open the report displaying only the matching record (`id` is the primary key):

```vb
DoCmd.SetParameter "which_id", 4
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFoo",acViewReport
```

Or, because of the `OR [which_id] Is Null` condition in the query's `WHERE` clause, I can assign Null to the parameter before opening the report if I want all records included regardless of their `id` values:

```vb
DoCmd.SetParameter "which_id", Null
```

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know about this. (old dog & new tricks, I guess)

Comment: Great suggestion!  I never knew about that command.  One more thought for future viewers: what I needed was to output a report to a PDF that used a query with parameters.  I couldn't output the file directly without opening the file first.  As such, I called `DoCmd.SetParameter` for each parameter, then `DoCmd.OpenReport "reportName", acViewPreview, , , acHidden` to open the report while hidden, and then `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "reportName", acFormatPDF, filePath` to output it to a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you would open the query in VBA, you could supply the parameter. But since the report is the only one who calls the query, the query will ask for its parameter.

If you can't change the query, you'll have to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the parameter value from a form that will open this report using the syntax Forms![form name]![control name], so the query needs to be changed something like
Select * from [table name] where time_id= Forms![form name]![control name] 
this will make sure the the query gets parameter from the form's control and it won't prompt parameter.
But it only works if you open that query when this form is kept open/loaded...otherwise it will prompt like parameter again.

The Docmd.setparameter  in Access 2010 seems to be a very good suggestion where it keeps flexibility and good programming.